# Using variable and ID in Javascript

Tags: javascript

trying to change the css background of a DIV tag.
But I need to put a random image (currently saved as 1.jpg 2.jpg... 4.jpg) as the background
I get a random number through JS, my problem occurring is actually allocating that random number as the value to use when deciding what image to put in the DIV tag.

Here's what I got:

```
var slotImage = new Array();

slotImage[0]=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
slotImage[1]=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
slotImage[2]=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);

var findReplacementID, putReplacementImage;

for (findReplacementID=0;findReplacementID<3;findReplacementID++) 
{           

    for (putReplacementImage=0;putReplacementImage<4;putReplacementImage++) 

    {
        if (slotImage[findReplacementID] == putReplacementImage) 

        {
        alert(slotImage[findReplacementID].toString());
        document.getElementById('image' + findReplacementID).style.backgroundImage= 'url(pictures/' + putReplacementImage + 'jpg)'; 
        }
    }
}
```

findReplacementID is the first loop (I need to change 3 separate DIV tags, each named image1,image2 and image3. Embedded within that is another loop, putReplacementImage which goes through four times to compare the current random number with what value is stored in the slotImage index of each random number, if they are equal, I want to replace the background with the corresponding image in the folder.

Sorry if this seems a little long winded. The error I'm getting on error console is

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('image' + findReplacementID).style')
```

Any idea guys? If it doesn't make much sense or TL/DR the main problem I'm having is putting a variable and and ID name together when editing the background of a DIV tag.

Comment: It is telling you there is no 'image1' or 'image2' or 'image3' in your html.  Can we see your html or a JSFiddle/JSBin?  Also, are you planning to replace the image with `pictures/0jpg` or `pictures/0.jpg`?

Comment: <div id="image1" name="1"> </div>

<div id="image2" name="2"> </div>

<div id="image3" name="3"> </div>

edit: thats my html? sure ill boot up jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/lukes/NCT4Z/#&togetherjs=7Jeyl8GsVm

Comment: You realize you don't need `</div>`, you can just put a slash before the closing tag.

Comment: Is your page loaded when you execute the script?

Comment: Yeah, the page loads and when I run it I get an alert of a random number between 0-3, and then the line to execute the change of background doesn't run and flags up that error

Comment: No, I mean are you wrapping this code in a `window.onload`?

Comment: oh no, its currently in a function when you click image1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`putReplacementImage` will sometimes be 0, so change it to `(putReplacementImage + 1).toString()`, and you're missing a `.` before `jpg`, so change it to `.jpg`, and finally, you're missing a close `)` in `url(`, so add `+ ')'`.  This should fix your problem.  Your code should now look like this:

```
document.getElementById('image' + (findReplacementID + 1).toString()).style.backgroundImage=
'url(pictures/' + putReplacementImage + '.jpg)';
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById()` just isn't finding an element with that `id`. `console.log('image' + findReplacementID)` and make sure an element with that `id` exists.

Comment: yeah, my ID's in html are <div id="image1" name="1"> </div> to 3, so I'm not quite sure whats going on?

Comment: Did you try to log `image+ findReplacementID`, though? You should make sure that's what you think it is. If that's returning an id that exists your HTML may just be really messed up.